pandas, determine if set value already exists in dataframe
I am checking to see if a tuple of unordered values is already in another list. I am new to Python, and so have not used sets much, but am a heavy pandas user and so was thrilled to find this question on checking to see if a slice of something is in another tuple.
The MRE is good for my use case, thank you to @forgetso, but I add one complication: each value in the frame is an unordered tuple.
import pandas as pd
c1 = [("a", "b", "c", "e"), ("f", "g", "j"), ("a", "z", "x", "q"), ("q", "w", "e", "r")]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": c1,
})

c1 = [("e", "c", "d", "a"), ("f", "g", "j"), ("a", "z", "x", "q"), ("q", "w", "e", "r")]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": c1,

})

So that the two frames look like this:
          A     
0   (a, b, c, e)
1   (f, g, j)   
2   (a, z, x, q)
3   (q, w, e, r)

and
          A     
0   (e, c, d, a)
1   (f, g, j)   
2   (a, z, x, q)
3   (q, w, e, r)

So for example the values from A in df2 are all already in A in df1, even though df.iloc[0, "A"] is in a different order.
Apologies for the complexity, but is a dataframe truly the best way to achieve what I'm after? Or should I pivot to sets?

We can not compare if a tuple in a list of tuple,cause tuples with same values and in different order are not equal. we can use set, the order of values is meaningless in it:
print(("a", "b") in [("b", "a"), ("e", "f")]) # False
print({"a", "b"} in [{"b", "a"}, {"e", "f"}]) # True

As you know, we can use isin function to compare if a series value in another series, so to see if df1.A's value in df2.A, so we can create their set value first and then compare:
# use for iteration to change every element in df1.A to set
df1_a_set = pd.Series([set(i) for i in 
df1.A])
print(df1_a_set)
df2_a_set = pd.Series([set(i) for i in df2.A])
print(df2_a_set)
print(df1_a_set.isin(df2_a_set))

0    {b, c, e, a}
1       {f, g, j}
2    {z, x, q, a}
3    {r, e, w, q}
dtype: object
0    {a, d, c, e}
1       {f, g, j}
2    {z, x, q, a}
3    {r, e, w, q}
dtype: object
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

However, if you want to compare whole dataframe, column by column, we may do it with three steps.Firstly, creating dataframe's transpose, cause we usually compare dataframes row by row, and we can save rows' compare result in a new column:
df1_t = df1.T
# result dataframe may look like:
              0          1             2             3
A  (a, b, c, e)  (f, g, j)  (a, z, x, q)  (q, w, e, r)
B             a          f             s             g
C             q          w             e             r

df2_t = df2.T
# result dataframe may look like:

          0          1             2             3
A  (e, c, d, a)  (f, g, j)  (a, z, x, q)  (q, w, e, r)
B             a          f             s             g
C             q          w             e             r

Then, to compare two dataframes, we need to prepare a function which can compare series as we mentioned before:
def is_in(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series):
    """
    to see if values in s1 in s2
    """
    # change s1's tuple value to set
    s1_set = pd.Series([set(i) for i in s1])
    # change s2's tuple value to set
    s2_set = pd.Series([set(i) for i in s2])
    return tuple(s1_set.isin(s2_set))

Finally, we can use df1_t.apply function to save compare result in a  new column:
 df1_t["in_df2"] = df1_t.apply(
    lambda row: is_in(row, df2_t.loc[row.name]),
    axis=1
)
# result may looks like:
              0          1             2             3                 in_df2
A  (a, b, c, e)  (f, g, j)  (a, z, x, q)  (q, w, e, r)  (False, True, True, True)
B             a          f             s             g   (True, True, True, True)
C             q          w             e             r   (True, True, True, True)


This is very useful, thank you. I did not know sets were this versatile. Is there any way to check without manually recreating a new set each time? My example has a large amount of instances.

I also don't see how the list comprehension works here; if I change the else clause to "else 0", output is still a set.

@plotmaster473 I had updated my answer, it may fit your needs. I use if elsestatement because I only want to change tuple value to set, as I see there also string value in your data;but it seems not necessary so I remove it.
